# Plot solution of partial integro-differentiatial equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I would like to plot solution to a differential equation using ParametricNDSolve3D. The indepedent variable f has arguments q and t where q represents angle between 0 and 2pi while t represents time. So, I would like to plot the solution on a circle and watch it evolve in time possibly using Manipulate function. But I am not able to do it. I keep getting error while plotting for reasons that are not clear to me.
[image: i would like the plot to be on a circle because the variable q represents angle. However, I keep getting error while plotting for reasons that are not clear to me.]

Comment: Please don't post images of the code, but the code itself so users don't have to type it. regards

Comment: I genuinely tried to post the code, however, I don't know how to integrate function of two variables over one variable only. I was able to do it in the format shown in screenshot but I can't copy it as a code snippet in the description. That's why I shared code as an image, I am unable to paste it in the description

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code slightly as

```
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[{D[f[q, t], t] == -f[q, t] + Max[0, a f[q, t] + 
   c D[f[q, t], q, q] - b Integrate[f[q, t], {q, 0, 2 Pi}] + 1], f[q, 0] == Cos[q] + 1,
   f[2 Pi, t] == f[0, t]}, f, {t, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 2 Pi}]
ParametricPlot3D[{f[q, 1] /. sol, Cos[q], Sin[q]}, {q, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

to add a periodic boundary condition in `q` and to eliminate a pair of curly brackets in `sol`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works:)